# discord.net - how to send link without embed

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm sending some text to discord using discord.net and c#:

```
var result = await client.SendMessageAsync(theText, false, Array.Empty<Embed>(), botname, imageUrl);
```

but I don't want any embed, and when the text contains a link an embed is automatically generated...
How could I prevent that? using null or Array.Empty() doesn't prevent the embed to show up...

Comment: An embed being generated from a link has nothing to do with the embed parameter in the SendMessage method. Discord does that automatically with links. Post a link manually and you'd see the same thing. To prevent it you need to wrap the link in `<>` ... example `<www.google.com>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. As @Anu6is mentioned in the comments, discord automatically shows an embed if you post a link. You can either prevent this by removing the following permission in the channels (or for the role) for your bot:

[image]

or by wrapping it into `<>` for example: `<https://google.com>`